# How to send data to another PHP file?

Tags: php

There is a href tag:

```
<a href="file.php">Send</a>
```

or a button (needs form tag)

```
<form action="file.php" method="GET">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

that will redirect to `file.php` URL.

I want to send `id` parameter to another PHP file. How do I do that?

==========================================================================

To send that data where must be provided input params (ex. hidden input) or in-url parameter.

ex.

```
<form action="file.php" method="GET">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="YOUR_ID"
</form>
```

or

```
<a href="file.php?id=YOUR_ID">Send</a>
```

Comment: Try to paste some code so we can easily help you. Include the scenario in which you are trying to model here please.

Comment: It's one of the basics when you learn working with DB in PHP. The answer is `yes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to transfer the id only to the next file? Use this in the first:

```
<a href="second.php?id=1">link_to_2</a>
```

or

```
<form...>
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="1">
<button type="submit">btn_to_2</button>
</form>
```

And in your second file use this for both cases:

```
<?= $_REQUEST['id'] ?>
```